# A broken Wubi has been detected. Ubuntu is unable to boot from hard disk

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04.04 alongside my Windows XP from USB, but it won't boot from hard disk, only from the USB.

I suspect that the reason is because I am unable to change BIOS to boot from dev/sdc since BIOS only offers the hard disk that corresponds to dev/sda.

I have tried running Boot-Repair to no avail. The most recent boot info from this http://paste.ubuntu.com/7189172/  for this one, I set the boot to go to sda and then point to sdc6 for Linux.

There is also the following cryptic message from Boot-Repair:

```
A broken Wubi has been detected. Please fix it this way:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu
```

That URL told me to close down Windows properly. However I can't boot into Windows, so that is pointless advice.

I also tried telling Boot-Repair to boot into Windows from the hard disk, but that made it so I couldn't even boot from the USB.

I appreciate any help that anyone can give. I don't know much about Linux, but I'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you boot from drive that is sdc or the 120GB drive does not grub boot Ubuntu?

You also should use advanced options in Boot-Repair and restore a Windows boot loader to sda. That should boot the Windows in sda if that is a bootable Windows.

On sdc use gparted to move boot flag from sdc8 to sdc1. Windows uses boot flag to know what partition to boot, what partition to repair to what partition to istall into. So boot flag needs to be on primary NTFS partition with Windows. Grub does not use boot flag. And if booting with grub you do not have to have boot flag on sdc1, but if you need to repair it or install a Windows  boot loader you will need boot flag on sdc1.

If you have any data in wubi you want to save, back that up. Otherwise in both sda1 & sdc1 delete wubi.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I figured out a simple solution, but it is good to know the reasons behind the "proper" solution.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the two drives that I couldn't boot from (because BIOS wouldn't let me) in the hopes that it would force Ubuntu to install on sda, as well as put the boot flag there.

I then reinstalled from the USB, and it worked!  Even booted windows xp correctly, although it wanted to do a CHKDSK, which I gladly obliged.

Simple solution.  I wish I had thought of it sooner.